# How can view a live processable image in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to create a viewer that uses the lazy pixel update technology to view a live video with low pixel change between frames (for example mouse pointer and drawing tools in a online lecture)

I have found that this library works well for image processing and update frames but I could not use it to display the image within Widget.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image

I tried to use image bytes (although this method is slow)

```
Image.memory (myImage.getBytes ());
```

But I got this exception

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
```

my code:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
          home: new HomePage(),
));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Uint8List bytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(child: Image.memory(bytes)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          update();
        });
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    update();
  }

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      bytes = Test.nextImage().getBytes();
    });
  }
}

class Test {
  static img.Image image = new img.Image(200, 200, Colors.red.value);

  static img.Image nextImage() {
    var rng = new Random();
    int w = rng.nextInt(image.width);
    int h = rng.nextInt(image.height);
    int c = rng.nextInt(256);
    image.setPixel(w, h, c);

    return image;
  }
}
```

So I want an effective way to view the image and the possibility of processing it in real time

Comment: What is "lazy pixel update technology"?

Comment: Get the next frame from the current frame by changing some color values of some pixels, so if the mouse pointer moves, only the pixels related to the old and new mouse pointer position will be updated to get the next frame. @jamesdlin